# Tags "dependency grammar" and "dependency"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I noticed some activity in adding [dependency](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dependency) to some questions that are already tagged with [dependency-grammar](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dependency-grammar).

At the time of this writing, there are 6 questions in [dependency](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dependency) and 49 in [dependency-grammar](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dependency-grammar) with 2 questions having both tags. [dependency-grammar](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dependency-grammar) has a tag wiki while [dependency](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dependency) hasn't.

What to do with this? Is there need for two different tags here or should the two of them be synonymised?

Comment: If there are no objections to it, I'll make the tags synonyms.

Answer (score 2):

"Dependency" does seem to be mostly associated with "dependency grammar", and most of the [dependency](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dependency) tagged questions do seem to be about DG, so a tag merge makes sense.

One exception to that generalisation is "dependent-marking languages" (as compared to head-marking languages). That's a typological term that gets used by constituency grammars. But it probably doesn't need its own tag.